# jQuery Fade object after 20 seconds of inactivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I want to fade out a div if a user hasn't made a **mouse click** for 20 seconds.

I have the following code:

```
if($('.main-popup2').is(":visible")){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.main-popup2').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 20000);
}
```

Problem is I don't know how to reset the setTimeout after detecting a user mouse click.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) method actually returns a reference to the *timer* it creates. This reference can be used in [.clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) to stop the timer before it executes.

Here is an example of how to use this:

```
var timer;

if($('.main-popup2').is(":visible")){
    // create the timer and save its reference
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.main-popup2').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 20000);
}

// when clicking somewhere on the page, stop the timer
$(document).click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}):
```

Comment: might be better to have the click on the `body`.  Not sure on what he wants the click to happen on to disable the `timeout`.  +1 nevertheless

Comment: Indeed, i have adapted my example.

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeout = null;
var fadeElement = $('.main-popup2');

function fader() {
    if(null !== timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    fadeElement.stop();
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {fadeElement.fadeOut('fast');}, 2000);
}

$(document).click(fader);
fader();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use delay function.

```
(window).click(function () {
   $('.main-popup2').delay(6000).fadeOut(300);
}
```

Each click restart 6 seconds, after it .main-popup2 fadeout if there isn't